# heroku cli commands not responding on windows 10

Tags: heroku-cli

I installed heroku cli on windows 10 via exe installer.

When i try to run `heroku --version` command or `heroku login`
command, the command window does not respond. It does not give any error.

Then i uninstalled it and installed it using `npm install -g heroku-cli`
but getting same result.

Node version - 8.7.0

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Windows cmd prompt, do:

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
```

Go to your C:\Users\**YOURNAME**

Look for a file named:

```
_netrc
```

This file stores login credentials. Delete it.

Then check for an update:

```
heroku update
```

Then try to log in:

```
heroku login
```

I saw some people create an environment variable called HOME and add the path to YOURNAME so the environment knows to look for the `_netrc` file there.

Other trouble-shooting ideas if the above doesn't work for you can be found at [Heroku CLI troubleshooting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1):

In windows , run %LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku, completely delete this folder. and check again on cmd by typing heroku --version. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up uninstalling heroku from the Windows Installer and instead used the standalone tarball.

You can get the tarballs from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#tarballs).
After you downloaded and extracted it, you can go to your terminal and `cd` into the directory where you extracted the file and do the following command:

```
./bin/heroku --version
```

Whenever you need the heroku CLI, you can `cd` into the directory where heroku is, then `./bin/heroku` is the executable for heroku.